making terminal look good without homebrew
Is there a way to make a terminal look nice without Homebrew? I have a Mac and for some reason I can't download homebrew (yes, I checked to see if I had all the requirements). I gave up on downloading it after spending 3 days trying. I watched a bunch of tutorials and all of them require homebrew in some shape or form. My terminal looks ugly, especially whenever I open vim. Does anyone know how I can make it look nice without homebrew? If not, then I'll just have to stick to VScode.
I changed the background color to pink and downloaded on my zsh. Other then that, the text is colorless and bland. T-T

I did not know that Homebrew can do something to  make your terminal look better, and I also don't know your aesthetic requirements of your terminal. I personally use for the command line most of the time iTerm2 instead of the stanadard Terminal.app, but mostly it's because I like the additional features. Both Terminal.app and iTerm2 can give colour to your text. In addition, zsh allows you to colour the text based on the syntactical meaning of the words in the command line. What else do you need?

I would probably look for a different terminal you like the look of already, might be the easiest option. Would personally recommend terminator, has a completely black background and nice colors, is also easily customizable with different fonts usw. Hope this helps!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
